# Select Python interpreter for VSCode project with activation in .bashrc

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, virtual-environment, mamba

I have several conda Python environments. In Visual Studio Code, for a project, I select the Pyhton interpreter I want to use. If I close and reopen VSCode, the previously selected interpreter is automatically used. However, this does not work if I activate a conda Python environments in my .bashrc file (`mamba activate python_env1`). If so, each time I open a project in VSCode, the default interpreter is the one activated in .bashrc.

I'd like to activate a default environment that I want to use in the Terminal and be able to specify a specific interpreter for my projects in VSCode. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using `"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "path\to\your\interpreter"` in settings.json?

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that. It has no effect if an environment is activated in .bashrc.

Comment: I guess you may have added `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "bash",` in settings. Trying to delete it may solve the problem

Comment: I don't have this in my settings. Neither in the user settings nor in the workspace settings. In the user settings, I have ```"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false"```. I don't know if that may be related.